# Angular CLI - Karma test build not finding ng2-material

Tags: angularjs, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I'm building out a new Angular 2 app with the Alpha Angular-CLI. I'm also using the [ng2-material](https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/) library. In order to even get it to work I had to do the following:

```
// index.html
System.config({
  packages: {
      app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js 
       },
      'ng2-material': {
          format: 'cjs',
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: 'all.js'
      }
  }
  });
  System.import('app.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));

// ember-cli-build.js
var materialTree = BroccoliFunnel('node_modules/ng2-material', {
    destDir: 'ng2-material'
});
```

It works fine in the app itself. However, when I run `ng test` I get the following error:

> START:
>
> 13 04 2016 14:55:36.982:WARN [web-server]: 404: /ng2-material/all
>
> Chrome 49.0.2623 (Mac OS X 10.11.3) ERROR
>
> Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/ng2-material/all
>
> ```
>  at error (/../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1026:16)
>
>  at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (/../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1047:13)
> ```
>
> 13 04 2016 14:55:37.058:WARN [web-server]: 404: /ng2-material/all

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your `karma-test-shim.js` try loading the module before loading your tests:

```
System.import('system-config.js').then(function() {
  // Load and configure the TestComponentBuilder.
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ]).then(function (providers) {
    var testing = providers[0];
    var testingBrowser = providers[1];

    testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(testingBrowser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      testingBrowser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  });
///////////////// Add this part /////////////////
}).then(function() {
  return System.import('/path/to/ng2-material.js/in/node_modules');
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
}).then(function() {
  // Finally, load all spec files.
  // This will run the tests directly.
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    }));
}).then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
```